# Strange characters in HTML mails on iOS

Tags: ios, wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm using phpMailer in a WordPress plugin to send HTML mails. This works very well. But unfortunataly some users have these strange characters on german Umlauts and the `&nbsp;` for instance.

This normally happens when using a different charset rather than UTF-8 but this is not the case. I don't allow users to change that and as long they don't change the code (what they don't do) there are no hooks or filters to change it too.

The strangest thing is when they send me the exact same message to me and I have no problems on my iPhone

Has anyone experienced similar? I hardly get this support request but every time I have to say that I don't know an answer.

Comment: Can you spend some time to clarify exactly where the problem is, what the conditions are, and WHERE the problem is happening. I'm like totally confused by the question as it is. Also, is this an iOS question - you said it works on the iPhone?

Comment: The problem is that exactly the same email has these characters on the iPhone of my user while it is fine on my iPhone (same device/iOS).
I can't tell if it's related to the iOS cause users can't change settings regarding encoding on this device (afaik).
What I know is that it is exactly the same mail on both devices. Also all other clients (outlook, thunderbird,..) display all mails correctly. Third point is that it'S hardly occur on the users side

Comment: You need to give more information about what you're seeing e.g. a screenshot or photo of the problem characters.

Comment: [this is a screenshot from an user](http://ticksy_attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5765101190.png)